# discord.py :: massban command not properly banning and sending embed messages upon completion

Tags: python, discord.py

Whenever I run my code in VSC, I'm not getting any errors in my terminal so I have no idea where to go from here.

When I run the command, it should be !massban   . Upon doing this, it should check to make sure the users are in the server or not as well as checking to make sure a reason is given. After, it should send the users an embed message telling them that they were banned and the reason for it while sending another embed to a log channel to show who actioned the user and the reason for it. Finally, the users will be banned while showing how many successful bans there were / how many failed.

Unfortunately, upon using this command, it does not check to see if the member is in the server or not as well as not checking if a reason is included. It will only ban the first ID given, not send an embed message to the user, and only sends one log to the mod log channel without saying how many successful bans there were / how many failed. (I was using alt accounts to test this on and they both have the ability to receive messages from my server.)

This is my code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Head Honcho", "Discord Moderator")
async def massban(ctx, member : commands.Greedy[discord.Member], *, reason: Optional[str]):
    if member is None:
        return await ctx.send("This member could not be found, or you did not provide an ID.")

    if reason is None:
        return await ctx.send("Please provide a reason for banning this user.")
    
    success = 0
    failures = 0
    for user in member:
        try:
            embed = discord.Embed(title = "You have been **banned** from  Cold's Jamboree " , description = "A moderator has banned you regarding your behavior." , color = discord.Color.from_rgb(204,0,0))
            embed.add_field(name = "Reason:", value = "{reason}".format(reason=reason) , inline = True )
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
            try:
                await member.send(embed=embed)
                await ctx.guild.ban(user, delete_message_days=1)
            except discord.HTTPException:
                pass

            success +=1

        except discord.HTTPException:
            failures +=1

        finally:
            channel = client.get_channel(820100484358471701)
            embed = discord.Embed(title = f"", description = "**[] A 'mass ban' has been issued.**", color = discord.Color.from_rgb(204,0,0), timestamp = ctx.message.created_at)
            embed.add_field(name = f" `{ctx.author.name}` has banned `{user.name}`.\n\nReason:", value = "{reason}".format(reason=reason))
            embed.set_author(name = f"{user} ({user.id})", icon_url = user.avatar_url)
            embed.set_footer(icon_url = ctx.author.avatar_url, text = "Modlog created ")
            try:
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
            except discord.HTTPException:
                pass

    if ctx.channel.id == 805651955841236993:
        reaction_emote = ("<:Checkmark:820467149554319410>")
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(reaction_emote)
        await ctx.send("Massbanned " + str(success) + " members.\n{}".format(f"Failed {failures} members." if failures else ""))
```

I would be extremely grateful if someone could help me out. With VSC not giving me any errors, I'm confused as to what's going on because it **should** work.

Answer (score 0):

you should not do this, discord hates when people do it because it's hard to tell from nuking (where people make bots to ban everyone) or if it's real so most of the time they will block it if it's not delayed like 10s or really slow.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29891896)